# HP Color LaserJet CP3525dn gives out error code 41.7 often

Tags: printer, hp-laserjet

We have a HP Color LaserJet CP3525dn printer in our network. Every now and then (quite often) it stops/pauses the printing process and gives out the 41.7 error code which I looked up and it means a temporary printing error has occurred. As the result of this error the printer also prints one or two pages that are almost empty but have a few faded lines of the document that was to be printed out.

- We are using the correct kind of paper
- We can continue the printing by pressing OK in the printer CP when the error occurs
- The hardware/insides of the printer should be in a very good condition

Has anyone else got this problem? Is there anything that can be done to avoid these errors? A firmware update? If so, how big of a chance is there to "brick" the printer when doing a firmware update?

I'm grateful for any information & solutions regarding this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated firmware on several HP printers without any trouble.
Just be sure you follow the procedure correctly.
http://goo.gl/QrhWX1

Comment: Thank you for your information! It makes me more confident to do the firmware upgrade if needed! Still I'm looking for more answers to the other part of my question to see if there are any people with experience on this error/problem. That way I can determine if the firmware upgrade is the only option or if there are some other solutions. :-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this specifiq error. Allthough it is quite common that firmware upgrades are needed to fix software issues on HP:s products.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the reason for error code 41.7 is that the rollers grabbing fresh paper are not sticky enough any more. In this case I used spray for climbing skins (e.g. colltex) to make them stickier again, and the problem was resolved. Be sure you use gloves and transfer some liquide on two fingers first and then apply the liquide as evenly as possible on the rollers.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix on a CP4525, remove tray 2 and then find the cassette rollers above the tray guide at center right. Not sure if its same configuration in 3525dn. Press the tabs in and slide the two larger rollers off without touching them (to avoid skin oils). Remember which was on the bottom and switch the placement of the rollers when you replace them (bottom goes on top sprocket and vice versa). Push them until they click. 41.7 should go away on tray 2

Then go and order a replacement set of rollers as a more permanent fix.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This printer has been replaced by a new machine of another brand. Still this can be of help to someone else!